# Get friends profile picture(s) from user table

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, mysqli

I have 2 table's:

**Users** (id, username, email, avatar, etc...);

**Friends** (id, user1, user2, status);

Now I want to build on my profile page an list of my friends with there avatar(s). I'm trying for like 4 hours by myself but i don't get it... :(

**BTW:** this is an error i got!

Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/reduaqi158/domains/reduankurtaj.eu/public_html/snapfriends/vrienden.php on line 26

This is what i have right now:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $status = 2;

    include "includes/conn.php";

    $vrienden=mysqli_query($server,"SELECT * FROM vrienden WHERE status='$status' && vriend1='$username' || vriend2='$username' ");

    $vriend_list = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($vrienden))
        {
            if ($row['vriend1'] == $username) {
                $vriend_list[] = $row['vriend2'];
            }
            else {
                $vriend_list[] = $row['vriend1'];
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($vriend_list);


    $foto=mysqli_query($server,"SELECT prof_pic FROM users WHERE username='$vriend_list['vriend1''vriend2']' ");
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($foto)) {

            echo "<img class='img-rounded' src=assets/profiel/".$row2['prof_pic']." alt='Card image cap'>";
        }

?>
```

json_encode output:

["ja","amando"]

Someone who can help me pls :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial approach is very confusing.

Almost everything in your code can be substituted by single `SQL` query.

You can use `JOIN` to get all your friends with their avatars in one go:

```
SELECT u.username as username, u.avatar as avatar,.... <== all columns which you need
    FROM `friends_table` f  <== your friends table
    JOIN `users_table` u    <== your users table
        ON (f.user1 = u.id) <== notice that i join on user1 column
    WHERE u.username = '$username' && f.status = '$status'
UNION
SELECT u.username as username, u.avatar as avatar,.... <== same columns
    FROM `friends_table` f  <== your friends table
    JOIN `users_table` u    <== your users table
        ON (f.user2 = u.id) <== notice that i join on user2 column
    WHERE u.username = '$username' && f.status = '$status'
```

By this query you select all users who are in a friendship with your $username. You need `union` because you don't know in which field (`user1` or `user2`) your `$username` is located.

**NOTE:** I strongly suggest using prepared statements instead of just putting '$var' inside `SQL` query to prevent SQL Injection.

After executing this query you can parse results and display avatars in such a way:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($vrienden, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<img class='img-rounded' src=assets/profiel/".$row['avatar']." alt='Card image cap'>";
}
```

I hope you got the idea.

Comment: i have changed some table names etc, but now i get a blank page :(

Comment: @ReduanKurtaj In order for me to provide working solution, you need to post your actual DB schema :) Also, look in your error log to see why you've got blank page.

Answer (score 0):

in your while statement you have to declare a value for the array. like array[0] = value. so that you know that array position 0 has a certain value. Like what I did here below. Don't know if it's in PHP like this but certain in .net you have to declare the location of a value in an array.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($vrienden))
    {
        if ($row['vriend1'] == $username) {
            $vriend_list[0] = $row['vriend2'];
        }
        else {
            $vriend_list[1] = $row['vriend1'];
        }
    }
```

and the following

```
$foto=mysqli_query($server,"SELECT prof_pic FROM users WHERE username='$vriend_list['vriend1''vriend2']' ");
```

shouldn't it be $vriend_list['vriend1'] . $vriend_list['vriend2']'

you have to use a connect character (the . in PHP)

Comment: In `php` you can push a value to array by `$array[] = $value` so it is not like in `.net`. Also concatenation doesn't make sense.